lsblk can see all drives attached but udev only shows half of them. Conflicting indentifiers?
I'm trying to make a zfs pool on a terramaster D8 Hybrid DAS connected via USB with 4x HDD and 4x NVME drives using this guide. When i try to build the get the drive ids to build the zpool, not all of them are reported by udev.
when i call lsblk i can see all of the drives in the das and the drive of the host pc:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk -d -o TRAN,NAME,TYPE,MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE
TRAN   NAME    TYPE MODEL     SERIAL               SIZE
       loop0   loop                               63.9M
       loop1   loop                                 64M
       loop2   loop                                 87M
       loop3   loop                                 87M
       loop4   loop                               49.8M
       loop5   loop                               38.8M
usb    sda     disk TDAS      800022304202         5.5T
usb    sdb     disk TDAS      800022304202         5.5T
usb    sdc     disk TDAS      A00022304202         5.5T
usb    sdd     disk TDAS      A00022304202         5.5T
usb    sde     disk D         0000000000000000   238.5G
usb    sdf     disk D         0000000000000000   238.5G
usb    sdg     disk D         0000000000000000   238.5G
usb    sdh     disk D         0000000000000000   238.5G
nvme   nvme0n1 disk 256GB SSD NJR368R008628P70GX 238.5G

But when i try to find the udev ids for the drives (needed to make the zpool), half of them are missing
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -lh /dev/disk/by-id
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Sep 29 05:04 nvme-256GB_SSD_NJR368R008628P70GX -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 29 05:04 nvme-256GB_SSD_NJR368R008628P70GX-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 29 05:04 nvme-256GB_SSD_NJR368R008628P70GX-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Sep 29 05:04 nvme-nvme.126f-4e4a52333638523030383632385037304758-323536474220535344-00000001 -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 29 05:04 nvme-nvme.126f-4e4a52333638523030383632385037304758-323536474220535344-00000001-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 29 05:04 nvme-nvme.126f-4e4a52333638523030383632385037304758-323536474220535344-00000001-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 29 05:04 scsi-1Realtek_RTL9220_1.010000000000000000 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 29 05:04 scsi-33001237923792379 -> ../../sdh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 29 05:41 scsi-35000000000000001 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 29 05:04 scsi-S256GB_SS_D_0000000000000000 -> ../../sdh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 29 05:41 scsi-STerraMas_TDAS_800022304202 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 29 05:04 scsi-STerraMas_TDAS_A00022304202 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 29 05:04 wwn-0x3001237923792379 -> ../../sdh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 29 05:41 wwn-0x5000000000000001 -> ../../sdb

It almost seems like udev is unable to create unique ids for these drives that have the same SN? These drives are new but not from the most reputable manufacturer. They were sold as WD reds and hdparm confirms:
SDA:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       WDC WD60EFRX-68L0BN1                    
    Serial Number:      WD-WXK8A4P18EOR

SDB:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       WDC WD60EFRX-68L0BN1                    
    Serial Number:      WD-WXK8A4P18ES6

Both SDA and SDB have different SN according to hdparm is the terramaster DAS breaking this uniqueness somehow? hdparm also shows that the drives both have different wwn but for some reason udev won't list by wwn?
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls  /dev/disk/by-wwn
ls: cannot access '/dev/disk/by-wwn': No such file or directory

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep -i wwn
S: disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000000000000001
E: ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION=0x5000000000000001
E: ID_WWN=0x5000000000000001
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000000000000001 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000000000000001 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-STerraMas_TDAS_800022304202

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sdb | grep -i wwn
S: disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000000000000001
E: ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION=0x5000000000000001
E: ID_WWN=0x5000000000000001
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000000000000001 /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000000000000001 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3.2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-STerraMas_TDAS_800022304202


Yes, it is as you say. For some reason udev sees the same IDs, so the by-id links overwrite one another. You could run udev without grep if there is any other property to distinguish them, or you could maybe check what these look like in /sys/block/… and come up with a custom udev rule for them. Or use a hardware independent identifier (PARTUUID/LABEL) if ZFS allows those.

For PARTLABEL you'd have to give them good, unique names in the GPT partition table. If you like the serial number you could just set that as part of the name.

Thanks for your response. I tried using part uuid but i think ZFS will only allow you to create pools with block stores (not partitions) as far as i can tell.
